# Intel x64 Opcodes

Tags: x86, 64-bit

What do the /r, /0, /2, and /4 characters mean in x64 Opcodes?  I assume /r means a ModR/M byte but what do /0 /2 and /4 mean?  For example the 'Add 8-bit immediate to r/m8' instruction encoding is 80 /0 ib (page 457)...

Comment: Can you say what document you are reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an explanation section right before the instruction list starts (the numbers may differ between different version):

```
3.1.1.1 Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table

...   

/digit — A digit between 0 and 7 indicates that the ModR/M byte of the
instruction uses only the r/m (register or memory) operand. The reg field
contains the digit that provides an extension to the instruction's opcode.
```

So these digits show a part of the opcode. If you check the example you gave, you'll see that the opcodes 80 \2 (ADC) and 80 \4 (AND) are completely valid, and represent different instructions.

Comment: If not, how would the CPU differentiate between the above cases? It's just a way to use extra bits for the opcode